# Showing Collection data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
var FriendsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FriendModel,
    url: '/friends'
});

var friends_collection = new FriendsCollection();
```

in the template of a View I have to access the first name of the data received from the REST like this

```
<% _.each(friends, function(friend) { %>
<div style="background-color: #fff">
<%= friend.friends[0].Friend.first_name %>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Is there anyway that when the `friends_collection .fetch()` is called, instead of adding a json object, it actually adds instances of the Model attached to the Collection?

Comment: It needs to be JSON for the template to parse it. You can loop over the collection in your template or you could loop over it in your view and create a child view for each element. The JSON you pass to the template in the subviews could be the individual FriendModels.

Comment: yes, to the template i'm sending this.collection.toJSON() from the View.  but the collection doesn't have the FriendModel instances - it has JSON already in it - and that is all done automatically by the `.fetch()` method

Comment: So the JSON you pass to your template doesn't contain a list of friends? If so, I'd say there's something wrong with your REST call. Try putting a breakpoint in the render method of your view. If you inspect the collection do you see a list of friend objects?

Comment: yes eventually there is a Friend object.  as you can see from the code, it's the last part: `Friend.first_name` - Friend is actually refering to the FriendModel

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you're asking. Is the problem that you can't loop over the data?

Comment: no no, I can loop the data; I want to have a less JSONed data - i.e. when looping, i want to output the data just by doing `friend.first_name` not `friend.friends[0].Friend.first_name`.  I updated the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36382/discussion-between-hex4-and-net-uk-sweet)